# How to Generate HTML from within ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: .net, html, asp.net-mvc, dynamically-generated

### My english very terrible, so i cant explain very clear. I will try my best.

is it possible to generate HTML code from within ASP.NET MVC, please?

**This is Controller**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = "Hello ASP.NET MVC!";
        ViewData["author"] = "Author: Alex";


        return View();
    }
```

**This is Views**, It's a template.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
title
```

### <%: ViewData["Message"] %>

<%=ViewData["author"]%>

<%=Html.ActionLink("This is a link.", "Index", "About") %>

I want to use this template generate html file.

---

Have a nice day,

Alex

Comment: This is like asking if chefs prepare food.

Comment: Judging by Gordon Ramsey's show jfar, chefs just yell at people.

Answer (score 5):

By generate html I'm assuming you mean programmatically and are not referring to views which of course you can put html in.

In a html helper or controller you can use the TagBuilder to generate html. For example..

```
TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("img");
tag.Attributes.Add("id", "myImage");
tag.Attributes.Add("src", "/Content/Images/some_image.png");
tag.Attributes.Add("alt", "my image");
tag.Attributes.Add("width", "300");
tag.Attributes.Add("height", "300");

string html = tag.ToString();
```

You can also use HtmlTextWriter which is a little bit similar.

```
HtmlTextWriter writer = new HtmlTextWriter(stream);
writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Ul)
// dome some stuff
writer.RenderEndTag();
```

etc.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

You can generate HTML by adding C# code to a view.